# How to specify custom migration table in beego

Tags: go, beego, golang-migrate

I have 2 repo which uses the same database. I have different migrations in each repo. how can I specify a custom migration table in 1 repo rather than the default *migration* table in Beego?

Beego version 1.10.1

Go version go1.10.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not currently possible with beego, it uses hardcoded table name `migrations` as you can see in the source code - https://github.com/astaxie/beego/blob/develop/migration/migration.go#L149

But since it is open source, it can be improved with a PR!